# Cannot delete dynamically created SVG paths

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I have some dynamically created SVG paths which connect some div. And on clicking on the paths they are deleted. The problem is I am only able to delete the paths in a LIFO order because of the way the SVGs are styled. They are stacked on top of one another as they are added so I am unable to access the ones that were added before. How do I fix this?

```
<div class="boundary">
    <div ng-repeat="edge in edges track by $index">
        <svg id="svg">
            <path id="boxPath_{{edge.id}}" class="boxPath" ng-click="deleteEdge(edge)"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```
$scope.deleteEdge = function(edge){
   var index = $scope.edges.lastIndexOf(edge)
   $scope.edges.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: If all of your svgs are same width and height and stacked over one after another (exactly in same size), how would you click and delete the below specific svg? Can you also add you js/jquery too?

Comment: what if you `<path ng-repeat="edge in edges track by $index" id="boxPath_{{edge.id}}" class="boxPath" ng-click="deleteEdge(edge)"></path>`?

Comment: @yeyene that is exactly my problem. The SVG height and width need to be at least equal to the .boundary.And yes I can add js/jquery but the logic needs to be handled inside the angularjs script file so that I can delete the edge from the array.

Comment: @Thomas I have tried this but it is not working.

Comment: In `deleteEdge` you search for `edge` in one array but try to remove it from a different one?

Comment: Set your svgs' `pointer-events` to `none` and their content's (`svg *`) to `all`.

Comment: This solves it,thanks. @Kaiido